# Gem Install Bundler via batch script in Windows - process gets killed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to automate a ruby app deployment on a Windows machine with a batch script.

Everything is going dandy, except for the following line:

```
gem install bundler
```

If I type this in manually, all goes well.  If I use a batch script, however, the process is killed as soon as the installation completes.  This is what I'm using:

```
pause
gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
pause
```

I've tried with the -f switch and also all docs; nothing seems to prevent the window from getting killed.  I need the process to stay alive so I can bundle install.  Any idea why this is happening, and how I can keep it alive post-install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gem` is a batch file (`gem.bat`). When you're invoking a batch file from another one, it is transferring control to it and not resuming.

You should try using `CALL` instead:

> CALL a second batch file 
>   The CALL command will launch a new batch file context along with any specified arguments. 
>   When the end of the second batch file is reached (or if EXIT is used), control will return
>   to just after the initial CALL statement.

Documentation here:
http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

You can also avoid the batch file by doing `ruby -S gem ...` which is more verbose and will work since there is a `gem` (extensionless) file along `gem.bat`.

Hope that helps.